# Ошибка при установке vue через @vue/cli

Tags: vue.js, npm, консоль, warning

Столкнулся с ошибкой при первой установке `Vue` через `npm install -g @vue/cli`.
  Она выглядела так: [image: Она выглядела так:]В добавок к ней шли сообщения о угрозе безопасности, а при прописывании команды `npm audit fix --force`, выскакивала ошибка «Невозможно загрузить файл ….ps1, так как выполнение сценариев отключено в этой системе»:[image: Скриншот прилагаю:]
Ниже напишу причину и мое решение проблемы, которое оказалось довольно простым.

Answer (score 1):

Причина ошибки в том, что в системе Windows по умолчанию запрещено запускать пакетные файлы, скрипты PowerShell. Чтобы решить эту проблему, нужно зайти в PowerShell от имени администратора и ввести команду: 
 `Get-ExecutionPolicy` , если вы получаете значение `Restricted`, то пропишите команду: 
 `Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted`, а когда поступит запрос, введите ключ `Y`. Все, проблема решена, и если вы сделали все по инструкции, то у вас должно получиться скачать Vue через `npm install -g @vue/cli`. Надеюсь мое решение было полезным, удачи в освоении крутого фреймворка!!!